# Output from ruby -v is repeated with rbenv

Tags: ruby, bash, osx-mavericks, rbenv

Yesterday I installed rbenv on a new MacBook Pro (OS X Mavericks, bash) and, although everything seems to be working, if I'm in a directory with a `.ruby-version` file and the given ruby version isn't installed, this happens:

```
$ cat .ruby-version 
1.9.3-p327
$ ruby -v
rbenv: version `1.9.3-p327' is not installed
rbenv: version `1.9.3-p327' is not installed
```

My `.profile` looks like this:

```
$ cat ~/.profile 
PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH

eval "$(rbenv init -)"


### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

And here's my path:

```
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/simon/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Does anyone know why the output from `ruby` is duplicated?

Comment: And what is output for `which ruby`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev `/Users/simon/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this seems to be the "normal" behavior. All the machines I have running here show the message twice as well.

Comment: This is the third OS X machine I've installed rbenv on in the last 6 months and I'm sure I haven't seen it happen before.